# Your device isn't compatible with this version for some devices

Tags: android, sdk, google-play, installation

Sorry I know this question is already done, but I have not found solution on the posts I've read.
I updated my app and now I can not download from Play Store in some devices as Nexus 5.
I don't know why Google says my device isn't compatible, this is the manifest from my app.

I already checked on the compatible devices list and Nexus 5 is available, also the apk size is only 24 MB (in some other post refers this problem should happen because of .apk size).

Thanks in advance for any help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.app.test.android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="75"
    android:versionName="3.4">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.app.test.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.app.test.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi" 
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".TestAppApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestAppstyle">

        <service android:name="com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="intent.my.action" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.app.test.android" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".services.GCMListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.GCMInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".services.GCMRegistrationIntentService" />

        <service android:name=".util.Service" />
        <service android:name=".util.Server" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my .gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.app.test.android"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 23
       multiDexEnabled = true
   }

   dexOptions {
       preDexLibraries = false
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
       incremental true
   }

   lintOptions {
       quiet true
       abortOnError false
       disable 'googlemapssdkm4b_lib'
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
       }
   }
}

buildscript {
   dependencies {
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
   }

   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   }
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:'
   compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
       transitive = true;
   }
   compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.0.1@aar'){
       transitive = true
   }
}
```

Comment: have you checked for your minSdk and targetSdk from build.gradle file.

Comment: paste build.gradle file of andrid Studio project

Comment: Yes, I have set  `minSdkVersion 15` and `targetSdkVersion 23` but problem happens in Android 6

Comment: @Margge yeah for making it compatible you have to use latest librarydependencies.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar I updated my post with gradle file

Comment: extract the manifest from your apk and check that - it maybe not what you expect.  ie, the build process may have added/changed something

Answer (score 0):

I know long time ago has passed, but I finally found the answer and maybe it could be helpful for someone else.

It wasn't something related with the app code. I was releasing the app in progressive mode and because of that some users were not able to download the app.

For me this is a weird message the Google Play Store displays to users because they get confuse.
The message disappeared when I released the app at 100%